# bubble sort in descending order

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, for-loop, bubble-sort

```
int main()
{
    int a[7] = {4,33,11,8,12,123,2}, temp;

    for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = 7; j > 7 - i; j--)
        {
            if (a[j] > a[j - 1])
            {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j - 1];
                a[j - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";

}
```

Hey, I want to sort numbers for bubble descending sort, but I have a problem, my code works with (ai >= 0) and when I enter negative numbers wrong output is given.
for example when i entered {4,33,-1,8,12,123,2}, output is

```
123 33 12 8 4 2 0
```

Comment: You have an off-by-1 error. Your array has elements a[0] through a[6], but you're starting your loops at 7.

Comment: It's just a coincidence that your program appears to work sometimes - you're indexing outside the array, and that has undefined behaviour.

Comment: As already stated you have an off by one error, but why are you using descending loops? They are harder to understand and are perhaps the reason you made the off by one error in the first place. Just because you are sorting in descending order doesn't mean you have to use a descending loop for bubble sort.

Comment: The reversed loop of `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) ...` is `for (int i = n-1; i >=0; i--)...`. There is no point in reverse-looping here. If you did it for practice, you have now noticed why everyone hates reversed loops.

Comment: @ayco If an array has 7 elements then the valid range of indices is [0, 7) that is you may not use the expression a[7].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior because within the loops you are trying to access memory beyond the array.

That is in the inner loop

```
    for (int j = 7; j > 7 - i; j--)
    {
        if (a[j] > a[j - 1])
        {
            temp = a[j];
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
            a[j - 1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

the initial value of the variable `j` is `7` and you are using this value to access elements of the array in the if statement.

In fact in the first iteration of the loop you have

```
        if (a[7] > a[6])
```

but `7` is not a valid index to access elements of the array.

It will be simpler to write the loops with indices starting with 0. All what you will need is to change the comparison expression in the if statement.

Nevertheless your updated program can look for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 4, 33, -1, 8, 12, 123, 2 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
        
    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    for ( size_t i = N; i != 0; --i )
    {
        for ( size_t j = N; --j != N - i;   )
        {
            if ( a[j-1] < a[j] )
            {
                int tmp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j-1];
                a[j-1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
        
    for ( const auto &item : a ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
4 33 -1 8 12 123 2 
123 33 12 8 4 2 -1
```

A more flexible approach is to write a separate template function which excepts two iterators of the category of the forward iterator.

In this case to sort an array in the descending order it will be enough to call the function with reverse iterators.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    
    int n, i, arr[50], j, temp;
    
    cout<<"Enter the Size (max. 50): ";
    cin>>n;
    cout<<"Enter "<<n<<" numbers: ";
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        cin>>arr[i];

        for (i=n; i!=0;--i)
        {
            for (j=n; j>(n-i); j--)
            {
                if (arr[j]>arr[j-1])
                {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[j-1];
                    arr[j-1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

    cout<<"\nThe New Array is: \n";
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```